# Static extension methods on Seq module

Tags: f#, extension-methods

According to [this post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2008/09/10/object-oriented-f-extension-everything.aspx), F# supports extension methods on object instances and static classes. For example:

```
module CollectionExtensions = 
    type System.Linq.Enumerable with   
        static member RangeChar(first:char, last:char) = {first .. last}

open ExtensionFSharp.CollectionExtensions
```

If I type `System.Linq.Enumerable.`, the static method `RangeChar` appears in my Intellisense window.

I want to add a static method, `for_alli`, to the Seq module. I've modified the following code above as follows:

```
module SeqExtensions =
    type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Seq with   (* error on this line *)
        static member for_alli f l =
            l
            |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> i, x)
            |> Seq.for_all (fun (i, x) -> f i x)
```

Although both snippets of code have the same structure, `SeqExtensions` doesn't compile. F# highlights the word `Seq` and returns the error "The type 'Seq' is not defined".

**How do I create static extension methods on Seq module?**

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To extend an F# *module*, just create another module with the same name:

```
module Seq =
    let myMap f s = seq { for x in s do yield f x }

Seq. // see your stuff here alongside normal stuff
```

Comment: See: [Type Extensions (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx) and notice the difference between `intrinsic extension` and `optional extension`.